# Grabbing objects from S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a route I've built in `nodejs` that basically, grabs all the objects in an S3 bucket. At the moment, I'm just console logging them out.

```
s3.listObjects({Bucket: 'store-generated-images'}).eachPage(function(err, data) {

    console.log(data.Contents);

})
```

and from this I get back an `object` that looks like:

```
     { DisplayName: 'servers',
       ID: '58af203151c51eddf2fdf1679211e0b91d274a8fda23f58280f9b06371e436f7' } },
  { Key: 'generatedi_images/e7_zysitb2tp8nr2t7cymjlf04emyzbd8_q02_.png',
    LastModified: Sat Apr 23 2016 10:16:46 GMT+0100 (BST),
    ETag: '"33ff7046c9ffe29775672825ca16c1de"',
    Size: 499304,
    StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
    Owner:
```

I get a list of these displaying in my terminal until it errors out. My error is :

```
/path/to/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Contents' of null
```

My question. Does this error mean there's no more objects in the S3 bucket?

How do I know when i've got all the objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that error means that there is no more data in S3. But I think you can use more efficient code as below:

```
s3.listObjects({Bucket: 'store-generated-images'}).eachPage(function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error in fetching data' + JSON.stringify(err));
    } else {
        if(data && data.Contents) {
            console.log(data.Contents);
        } else {
            console.log('No data in S3!');
        }
    }
})
```

Just try logging if you are getting any error from the error-first method.

Comment: Cheers man! Yeah, I think handling it the way you are is a lot better. I had a look at the documentation but couldn't find anything that told me how i'd check if i've gotten all objects in the S3 bucket or not